# Adding new user to just created object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user method:

```
@transaction.atomic
def create_company(self, **kwargs):
    new_company = Company.objects.create(**kwargs)
    new_company.admin_users.add(self)
    new_company.users.add(self)
    return new_company
```

It works, but I'm not sure this is a best practice for object create additional stuff. How should I fix it to make better and simplier? Is it ok to use `signals`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use signals as well:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_company(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Company.objects.create(admin_users = instance, new_company = instance)
```

I recommend using the kwargs `created` to launch your signal only if a new Company is created.